# What is wrong with this function I wrote to see if two arrays are sorted in ascending order, in C?

Tags: arrays, c, sorting, for-loop, function-definition

So here is the function:

```
int VerifTri(int t[], int g[], int n, int m)
{   int k, l; int sorted, sorted2;
    sorted = 1; sorted2 = 1;


    for (k=0; k<n; k++)
    {
      if( t[k] > t[k+1] )
            sorted=0;
    }


  for (l=0; l<m; l++)
  {
    if  (g[l] > g[l+1])
       {
        sorted2=0;
       }


  }

     if ((sorted == 1) && (sorted2 == 1))
        return 1;
     else
        return 0;


}
```

There is no syntax error, but the code is just wrong: I used it in a program and I entered two sorted arrays and it still returned 0.

Comment: What is `s2 = sorted 1;` supposed to do?

Comment: What is `n`? It `n` is array's length, then the *range* is *incorrect*: it should be `for (k = 0; k < n - 1; k++)`, note `k < n - 1`

Comment: oh that's a typo when i copied the code, i'll correct it

Comment: Side note: you can `return 0`; instead of `sorted=0;` and `sorted2=0;` if any array is not sorted there's no need to further process

Comment: Loops run for one too many iterations since you do `index+1` in each.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `n` is a length of `t` and `m` is a length of `g` you can put

```
int VerifTri(int t[], int g[], int n, int m)
{   
    int k; 

    for (k = 0; k < n - 1; k++)
      if ( t[k] > t[k+1] )
        return 0;

    for (k = 0; k < m - 1; k++)
      if ( g[k] > g[k+1] )
        return 0;

    return 1;
}
```

Please, note the range: `k == [0 .. n - 1)` otherwise the last comparison will be incorrect one

```
 t[n - 1] > t[n]
```

Same for `g` array

When we found any array being unsorted we can `return 0`: if an array is not sorted, *both* of them can't be sorted

Answer (score 0):

> what is wrong with this function i wrote to see if two arrays are
> sorted in ascending order, in C?

The function is initially wrong independent of its body because there is no great sense to define such a function instead of defining a function that checks whether an array is sorted.

Having such a function you can check in the caller whether two arrays are sorted the following way

```
int sorted = VerifTri( t, n ) && VerifTri( g, m );
```

Or you can even check whether three arrays are sorted like

```
int sorted = VerifTri( a1, n1 ) && VerifTri( a2, n2 ) && VerifTri( a3, n3 );
```

Moreover the parameters of the function that denote arrays should have qualifier `const` because the passed arrays are not changed within the function. And the parameters that denote sizes of the arrays should have the type `size_t`.

Within the for loops there is an attempt to access memory beyond the arrays in these if statements

```
if( t[k] > t[k+1] )
```

and

```
if  (g[l] > g[l+1])
```

when `k` is equal to `n-1` or when `l` is equal to `m-1`.

And the loops should be interrupted as soon as a previous element of the array is greater than the next element of the array.

So your function should look for example the following way

```
int VerifTri( const int a[], size_t n )
{
    size_t i = 0;

    if ( i != n )
    {
        while ( ++i < n && !( a[i] < a[i-1] ) );
    }

    return i == n;
}
```

And if you want to check whether two arrays are sorted then you can just write as shown above the expression

```
VerifTri( t, n ) && VerifTri( g, l )
```

If you want to check whether one of the arrays is sorted then you can write the expression

```
VerifTri( t, n ) || VerifTri( g, l )
```

Using your original function you will be unable to do this and have to write one more function.

Answer (score 0):

There are some problems in your code, some benign, some major:

- the code is badly indented: this makes it hard to read, with more places for bugs to hide.
- the loops are incorrect: assuming `n` is the length of `t` and `m` is the length of `g`, the last comparison will reference an element beyond the end of the arrays.
- the code is inefficient: you could return 0 as soon as any comparison evaluates to false.
- the name `l` for a variable is risky as it looks dangerously similar to `1` in common fixed width fonts.
- the prototype could be improved: the array pointers should be defined as `const` since the function does not modify their contents.
- your function is too specific: calling a simpler function that checks a single array is simpler and less confusing.

Here is a modified version:

```
int VerifTri(const int t[], const int g[], int n, int m) {
    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
        if (t[i - 1] > t[i])
            return 0;
    }
    for (int i = 1; i < m; i++) {
        if (g[i - 1] > g[i])
            return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}
```

For illustration, here is a simpler function to test a single array:

```
int VerifTri(const int *t, size_t n) {
    for (; n --> 1; t++) {
        if (t[0] > t[1])
            return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}
```